# NI-6281 Python error

Tags: python, nidaqmx

I have problems with data acquisition using National Instruments and Python. I use magnetic field sensors with 3 axes x, y, z, and I am using National Instruments library(Python) to get data. I made the setting to collect 100 data for every 1 second, and they return 3 lists with 100 elements for every one second.

```
time_memory = [k + i/100 for i in range(100)] # dividing 1 second into 100     intervals
x = [100 elements]
y = [100 elements]
z = [100 elements]
```

Below one is for writing data into files.

```
for i in range(self.samples):
    self.time_memory[i] = file_time + self.time_index[i] 
    f.write("{0} {1} {2} {3}\n".format(self.time_memory[i], x[i], y[i], z[i]))
```

So, the resulting data files must be look like this.

```
time_value, x, y, z
time_value, x, y, z
1.01, 32, 36, 123
1.02, 32, 38, 123.4
...
```

So I tried to get the data as long as possible, but after 8000 seconds, the program showed the weird error as shown in the photo.

It is shown that

```
The application is not able to keep up with the hardware acquisition. 
Increasing the buffer size, reading the data more frequently, 
or specifying a fixed number of samples to read instead of all available samples
might correct the problem. Property: DAQmx_Read_RelativeTo Corresponding Value:
DAQmx_Val_CurrReadPos Property: DAQmx_Read_Offset Corresponding Value: 0 
Task Name: _unnamedTask<0> Status Code: -200279
```

In order to solve this error, I googled and asked to many people, but I couldn't find the actual cause. 
The most convincing answer among them was that for a computer with HDD, writing 400 data less than 1 second (using for loops in Python) is much beyond the computer's capability, but I still can't believe this one and can't find the solutions to solve this problem.

Please help me guys :(

[image]

Comment: Copy the error. Don't take screenshots.

Comment: For the record, in Python2, result of `[i/100 for i in range(100)]` is a list with 100 zeros. `[i/100.0 for i in range(100)]` gives decimals.

Comment: Please add your Python code that configures the DAQ task.